# Calling user defined functions with Create Table in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I am getting an error while calling the user defined function while creating table in PostgreSql

Function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nextval_special()
  RETURNS text AS
 SELECT 'T'||to_char(nextval('entity_collector_team_team_code_seq'), 'FM10000')

 LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE

 COST 100;
```

Table is:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable1
(
id integer,
  teamcode   AS (dbo.nextval_special())
  )
```

I am getting following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
>
> LINE 4:   teamcode   AS (dbo.nextval_special())

entity_collector_team_team_code_seq its a sequence it generate sequence number like 1. 
After creation of table I am expecting output as T10001 and T10002 in sequence itself.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does not have computed columns.

You probably meant to assign a default value to the column:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable1
(
  id        integer,
  teamcode  text not null default dbo.nextval_special()
);
```